# State of check box in android listview

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, android-checkbox

I want to get all the family id selected from the list view. I add the family id in a separate
arraylist when click on the corresponding checkbox. The value in the arraylist losses when i scroll the listview.

Following is my code.

```
    public class FamilyList extends Activity{
ListView fam_list;
DataAdapter myadapt;
ArrayList<ListClass> familyarraylist;
ArrayList<String> familyselectedlist;
Button show;
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.i("zacharia", "inside oncreate");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_familylist);
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
fam_list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.familylist);
myadapt=new DataAdapter(this);
final TextView empty=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
empty.setText("No Data Found");
familyarraylist= myadapt.getfamilylist("All");
FamilyListAdapter familyadapter=new FamilyListAdapter(this, R.layout.family_list_view,familyarraylist);
fam_list.setAdapter(familyadapter);
fam_list.setEmptyView(empty);


familyselectedlist=new ArrayList<String>();

ImageButton button=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText edit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        if(edit.getText().length()>0){
            if(myadapt==null){
            myadapt=new DataAdapter(FamilyList.this);
            }
             familyarraylist=myadapt.getfamilylist(edit.getText().toString());
            fam_list.setAdapter(new FamilyListAdapter(FamilyList.this, R.layout.family_list_view, familyarraylist));                }
        else{
            if(myadapt==null){
                myadapt=new DataAdapter(FamilyList.this);
                }
            familyarraylist=myadapt.getfamilylist("All");
            fam_list.setAdapter(new FamilyListAdapter(FamilyList.this, R.layout.family_list_view,familyarraylist ));    
        }
        fam_list.setEmptyView(empty);

    }
});


show=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        for(int i=0;i<familyselectedlist.size();i++){
            Log.i("zacharia", familyselectedlist.get(i));
        }
        MainActivity.selected_list=true;
        MainActivity.selected_family_id_array=familyselectedlist;           
        FamilyList.this.finish();

    }
});
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_list, menu);
return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(item.getItemId()==R.id.item1){
    final SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("search_mode",  Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    int pos=prefs.getInt("position", 0);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Search By")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(new String[]{"Name","House Name"}, pos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Editor edit=prefs.edit();
                    edit.putInt("position", which);
                    edit.commit();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
}
return true;
}
static class ViewHolder {
protected TextView id_text,id_name,id_address;
protected CheckBox id_check;
   }
class FamilyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListClass>{

private ArrayList<ListClass> list_array;
Context context;


boolean checkchange=false;
ListClass obj;
public FamilyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<ListClass> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context=context;
    list_array=objects;

}

@Override
public ListClass getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list_array.get(position);
}

public int getFamilyId(int position){
    return list_array.get(position).getFamilyid();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=convertView;
    if(v==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.family_list_view, null);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        obj=getItem(position);
        holder.id_text=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_familyid);
        holder.id_text.setText(""+obj.getFamilyid());
        holder.id_name=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
        holder.id_name.setText(""+obj.getHeadname());
        holder.id_address=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_address);
        holder.id_address.setText(""+obj.getAddress());
        holder.id_check=(CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check_familyview);
        Log.i("zacharia", "check result:"+ getFamilyId(position)+"  "+familyselectedlist.contains(""+getFamilyId(position)));
        holder.id_check.setSelected(false);
        if(familyselectedlist.contains(""+getFamilyId(position))){

            holder.id_check.setSelected(true);
        }


        holder.id_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("zacharia", "inside on change");

                if(isChecked){
                    familyselectedlist.add(""+getFamilyId(position));
                }
                else{
                    familyselectedlist.remove(""+getFamilyId(position));
                }

            }
        });
        v.setTag(holder);
        holder.id_check.setTag(getFamilyId(position));
    }
    else{
        v=convertView;
        ((ViewHolder)v.getTag()).id_check.setTag(getFamilyId(position));
    }
    obj=getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    holder.id_text.setText(""+obj.getFamilyid());
    holder.id_name.setText(obj.getHeadname());
    holder.id_address.setText(obj.getAddress());
    if(familyselectedlist.contains(""+getFamilyId(position))){      
    holder.id_check.setChecked(true);
    }
    else{
        holder.id_check.setChecked(false);
    }

    return v;
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some changes to my code and pass an instance of an arraylist (for selected_ids) to the adapter it works.

Following is my code:

```
public class FamilyList extends Activity{
ListView fam_list;
DataAdapter myadapt;
ArrayList<ListClass> familyarraylist;
ArrayList<String> familyselectedlist;
Button show;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.i("zacharia", "inside oncreate");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_familylist);
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
fam_list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.familylist);
myadapt=new DataAdapter(this);
final TextView empty=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
empty.setText("No Data Found");
familyarraylist= myadapt.getfamilylist("All");
familyselectedlist=new ArrayList<String>();

FamilyListAdapter familyadapter=new FamilyListAdapter(this, R.layout.family_list_view,familyarraylist,familyselectedlist);
fam_list.setAdapter(familyadapter);
fam_list.setEmptyView(empty);




ImageButton button=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText edit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        if(edit.getText().length()>0){
            if(myadapt==null){
            myadapt=new DataAdapter(FamilyList.this);
            }
            familyarraylist=myadapt.getfamilylist(edit.getText().toString());
            fam_list.setAdapter(new FamilyListAdapter(FamilyList.this, R.layout.family_list_view, familyarraylist,familyselectedlist));             }
        else{
            if(myadapt==null){
                myadapt=new DataAdapter(FamilyList.this);
                }
            familyarraylist=myadapt.getfamilylist("All");
            fam_list.setAdapter(new FamilyListAdapter(FamilyList.this, R.layout.family_list_view,familyarraylist,familyselectedlist));  
        }
        fam_list.setEmptyView(empty);

    }
});


show=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        for(int i=0;i<familyselectedlist.size();i++){
            Log.i("zacharia", familyselectedlist.get(i));
        }

        MainActivity.selected_list=true;
        MainActivity.selected_family_id_array=familyselectedlist;           
        FamilyList.this.finish();

    }
});
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_list, menu);
return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(item.getItemId()==R.id.item1){
    final SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("search_mode", 0);
    int pos=prefs.getInt("position", 0);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Search By")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(new String[]{"Name","House Name"}, pos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Editor edit=prefs.edit();
                    edit.putInt("position", which);
                    edit.commit();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
}
return true;
}

class FamilyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListClass>{

private ArrayList<ListClass> list_array;
Context context;
ArrayList<String> selectedlist;
TextView id_text,id_name,id_address;
CheckBox id_check;

boolean checkchange=false;
ListClass obj;
public FamilyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<ListClass> objects,ArrayList<String> selectedlist) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context=context;
    list_array=objects;
    this.selectedlist=selectedlist;
}

@Override
public ListClass getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list_array.get(position);
}

public int getFamilyId(int position){
    return list_array.get(position).getFamilyid();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=convertView;
    if(v==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.family_list_view, null);

    }
    obj=getItem(position);
    id_text=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_familyid);
    id_text.setText(""+obj.getFamilyid());
    id_name=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
    id_name.setText(""+obj.getHeadname());
    id_address=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_address);
    id_address.setText(""+obj.getAddress());
    id_check=(CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check_familyview);

    id_check.setSelected(false);
    if(selectedlist.contains(""+getFamilyId(position))){

        id_check.setSelected(true);
    }


    id_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i("zacharia", "inside on change");

            if(isChecked){
                selectedlist.add(""+getFamilyId(position));
            }
            else{
                selectedlist.remove(""+getFamilyId(position));
            }

        }
    });

    id_check.setTag(getFamilyId(position));
    if(selectedlist.contains(""+getFamilyId(position))){        
    id_check.setChecked(true);
    }
    else{
        id_check.setChecked(false);
    }

    return v;
}


}
}
```

Now i need to show the selected items when i open this activity. How can i done that?  i try to pass it by the familyselectedlist to the adapter. If i uncheck the checkbox and scroll the check box status is remain as checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the following code out of if-condition (if (v==null)):

```
    holder.id_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i("zacharia", "inside on change");

            if(isChecked){
                familyselectedlist.add(""+getFamilyId(position));
            }
            else{
                familyselectedlist.remove(""+getFamilyId(position));
            }

        }
    });
```

You set listener only if you don't get a view for reusing. But you still have to set listener when you reuse existing view. So, if convertView is not null then it comes already with old onClickListener. This OnClickListener uses wrong position (from old view).

As a result you should set OnClickListener not only if (v == null).